# Gesture throwing unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to rewrite this line in Swift 3
**Swift 2:**
     let longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressDetected")

**Swift 3:**

```
let longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("longPressDetected")))
```

but it seems to be throwing this error

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The function that is's trying to call is this:

```
func longPressDetected(_ sender: Any){}
```

Comment: (target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding selector for

```
func longPressDetected(_ sender: Any){}
```

in Swift 3 is

```
#selector(longPressDetected(_:))
```

or even simply

```
#selector(longPressDetected)
```

---

Side-note: Since the sender is a distinct type you should specify this:

```
func longPressDetected(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){}
```

and don't annotate types the compiler can infer.